# I cannot listen to both Spotify and Zoom at the same time

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, spotify, zoom-meeting

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and it is fully updated via

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

I have a very strange issue, I have both Spotify and Zoom installed. Yet I can only listen to one at a time. If I begin listening to Spotify first, then Zoom tells me "your speaker is not working, please go to settings to try a different one" and will play no audio despite my microphone working.

However, if I turn on the the Zoom speaker test first and attempt to listen to Spotify then I hear the speaker test but not Spotify until I turn off the Zoom speaker test, do `pulse-audio -k` in terminal, and begin playing Spotify prior to resuming the Zoom speaker test.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I'm assuming its either a pulseaudio or ALSA issue since its not exclusively Zoom nor Spotify that has this problem.